# Django models: retrieving unique foreign key instances

Tags: django, django-models

I have two tables like so:

```
class Collection(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Image(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    image = models.ImageField()
    collection = models.ForeignKey(Collection)
```

I'd like to retrieve the first image out of every collection. I have attempted:

```
image_list = Image.objects.order_by('collection.id').distinct('collection.id')
```

but it didn't work out the way I expected :(

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: Are you using PostgreSQL? According to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct, the distinct feature with specific fields is only available there. Apart from that, shouldn't it be 'collection__id' instead of 'collection.id'?

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize that. I'm using MySQL

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't use dots to separate fields that span relations in Django; the double-underscore convention is used instead -- it means "follow this relation to get to this field"

this is more correct:

```
image_list = Image.objects.order_by('collection__id').distinct('collection__id')
```

However, it probably doesn't do what you want.

The concept of "first" doesn't always apply in relational databases the way you seem to be using it. For all of the records in the image table with the same collection id, there is no record which is 'first' or 'last' -- they're all just records. You could put another field on that table to define a specific order, or you could order by id, or alphabetically by name, but none of those will happen by default.

What will probably work best for you is to get the list of collections with one query, and then get a single item per collection, in separate queries:

```
collection_ids = Image.objects.values_list('collection', flat=True).distinct()
image_list = [
    Image.objects.filter(collection__id=c)[0] for c in collection_ids
]
```

If you want to apply an order to the Images, to define which is 'first', then modify it like this:

```
collection_ids = Image.objects.values_list('collection', flat=True).distinct()
image_list = [
    Image.objects.filter(collection__id=c).order_by('-id')[0] for c in collection_ids
]
```

You could also write raw SQL -- MySQL aggregation has the interesting property that fields which are not aggregated over can still appear in the final output, and essentially take a random value from the set of matching records. Something like this might work:

```
Image.objects.raw("SELECT image.* FROM app_image GROUP BY collection_id")
```

This query should get you one image from each collection, but you will have no control over which one is returned.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the double-underscore convention. Unfortunately the solution won't work with MySQL. I think I'll just iterate through each image and eliminate those with repeated collection ids.

Comment: I realised after I wrote it that it still wasn't doing what you wanted. I've edited the answer with a couple more possibilities.

Comment: Thanks, this solution makes the most sense to me but it doesn't seem to work. The line   collection_ids = Image.objects.values_list('collection', flat=True).distinct(), doesn't return distinct values for the collection id.

Comment: What does it return, then? Do you see a difference between `Image.objects.values_list('collection', flat=True)` and `Image.objects.values_list('collection', flat=True).distinct()` ? Try taking the len() of each of them to see what you get. Also, check django.db.connection.queries to see what is being sent to the database. There should definitely be a `SELECT DISTINCT` query being issued.

Comment: The SQL generated is using two fields for the distinct clause -- it looks something like: "SELECT DISTINCT 'pb_image'.'collection_id', 'pb_image'.'image' FROM ...".  Thanks for all your help but I think I'll be able to figure something out now.

Comment: No problem. If you are getting extra fields in your select, check for a default ordering on your models -- it can mess with `distinct`. You may need to add an explicit `.order_by()` to clear the default ordering out.

Comment: Yes! You're right, I just had to change the default ordering.

Answer (score 0):

As written in my comment, you cannot use specific fields with `distinct` under MySQL. However, you can achieve the same result with the following:

```
from itertools import groupby

all_images = Image.objects.order_by('collection__id')
images_by_collection = groupby(all_images, lambda image: image.collection_id)
image_list = sum([group for key, group in images_by_collection], [])
```

Unfortunately, this results in a "bigger" query to the DB (all images are retrieved).

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into this. I'm new to django so there's some unfamiliar stuff in this snippet.

Answer (score 0):

```
dict([(c.id, c.image_set.all()[0]) for c in Collection.objects.all()])
```

That will create a dictionary of the first image (by default ordering) in each collection, keyed by the collection's id. Be aware, though, that this will generate 1+N queries, where N is the total number of collection objects.

To get around that, you'll either need to wait for Django 1.4 and `prefetch_related` or use something like [django-batch-select](https://github.com/lilspikey/django-batch-select).

Answer (score -1):

> First get the distinct result, then do your filters.
>
> > I think you should try this one.

```
image_list = Image.objects.distinct()
image_list = image_list.order_by('collection__id')
```

Comment: This question was asked over 9 years ago and your answer is basically the same as the selected one, also from 9 years ago